# Can't shut down MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

When selecting the Apple on the top bar and then 'Shut Down' or 'Restart', Finder won't show the alert that asks you to confirm that you want to restart or shut down the computer (the one with the timer). Spotlight not working, and no dots under active apps...

I tried relaunching Finder but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to close all running apps first?

Comment: When I close all running apps the top bar disappears

Comment: Did you try to close all running apps but keep Finder running? Is this a one-off thing or does it happen regularly? Can you add a screenshot of the Force Quit dialog showing all running applications?

Comment: First time this is happening, Force Quit dialog when apps are running shows the apps but doesn't show Finder. I'm not sure how to show the Force Quit dialog with all the apps closed because when there's no apps running the top bar disappears.

Comment: If Finder is not running, the Shutdown/Restart commands aren't going to work. Try restarting Finder by clicking its icon in the Dock.

Comment: When right clicking on the Finder icon in the Dock is says on the top 'Application Not Responding'... If I click on 'Relaunch' nothing happens

Comment: Just hold down the power button for a very long time (I'm talking a minute or more) and the MacBook will shut down no matter what. You may need to release and then press down again to get it to start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still reboot your Mac even if the `Shut Down` prompt never appears: holding down the power button for at least 30 seconds will cause your Mac to force shut down, then releasing the power button and pressing and holding again until the Apple logo appears will allow you to start it up again.

If your Mac doesn't have a power button key, you can force  a shut down by pressing and holding <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>eject</kbd> .

[Source and more info here](http://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/how-to-shut-down-your-mac/).

**tl;dr:** Hold the power button for a while!